# Automatically indent file after command in Vim

Tags: vim, command, indentation

I am trying to write a custom vim command called Remove which takes a single argument and deletes all lines of the file that are exactly that argument. For example, if the file was

```
int main() {
    int x = 3;
    int y = 4;
    cout << x << endl;
}
```

and I use the command

```
:Remove int y = 4;
```

The output would be

```
int main() {
    int x = 3;
    cout << x << endl;
}
```

I can get pretty close by defining

```
:command -nargs=1 Remove :%s/<args>\n//g
```

But with this command the file is not indented properly after the substitution, which requires me to run gg=G afterwards.

Is there a way to make gg=G run automatically as part of the command?

Comment: Use the :normal command. Combine it with :execute if you need more than one command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. You can concatenate multiple commands with `|`. If this gets too long, you can factor out the code into a `:function`. Because `=` is a *normal mode* command, not an *Ex command* like `:substitute`, you need to invoke it via `:normal`; the `!` avoids that mappings interfere.

```
:command -nargs=1 Remove %s/<args>\n//g | normal! gg=G
```

Comment: Thanks! This was great for learning how | and normal! work in vim. I actually used yolenoyer's solution since it seemed a bit more elegant, but this response seems like the real answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

The indenting is wrong because your `Remove` command doesn't remove the leading spaces/tabs in the found lines.

Instead of reindenting all the file, you can modify your command to remove the spaces as well:

```
:command -nargs=1 Remove %s/^\s*\V<args>\n//g
```

- `^` matches the beginning of the line;
- `\s*` matches optional spaces or tabs; you could even put `\s*` again just before `\n`, to consider lines with hidden spaces at the end;
- I added `\V`, which avoids special regex chars in your command argument to be interpreted. If you don't put it, the following command:

  ```
  :Remove char *my_str = 0;
  ```

  would be misinterpreted because of the `*`.

Comment: Awesome! I ended up using this solution since it seemed a bit more elegant, although Karkat's solution was technically a more direct answer for my question as written.